# Многопоточное выполнение в jvm

Tags: java, многопоточность, jvm

Есть статьи о работе jvm с байт кодом , в них описываются opcodes, символические линки и связывание. Но нигде не описана работа в случае с многопоточным выполнением программы. Не подскажите где взять ?

Comment: @TagirValeev хотелось бы понять, отличия в работе между однопоточным и многопоточным выполнением. И что-нибудь почитать на эту тему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы интересуетесь написанием многопоточных приложений на Java, наилучшей книгой на эту тему является [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) (русского перевода как будто бы не существует, либо я плохо искал).

Если вас интересует внутреннее устройство JVM (например, какими системными вызовами достигается многопоточность в Windows или Linux, какие низкоуровневые примитивы синхронизации используются, в каких случаях в генерированный JIT-код вставляются барьеры памяти), то наилучший источник знаний — это [исходный код виртуальной машины](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm). С точки зрения JVM странно ставить вопрос об отличиях работы между однопоточным и многопоточным исполнением. JVM всегда многопоточна. Даже если вы пишете простое консольное приложение и не создаёте потоки явно, JVM сама создаёт отдельные потоки, которые занимаются JIT-компиляцией, сборкой мусора, финализацией объектов. И, конечно, эти потоки должны правильно синхронизироваться, поэтому многопоточность и конкуррентность там всегда работает. Если вы пишете, скажем, Swing-приложение, тут уже сам Swing вам потоков насоздаёт — и AWT-EventQueue, и SwingWorkers. Если это серверное приложение Java-EE, будет ещё больше потоков. Так что однопоточного режима в принципе нет.

Answer (score 2):

Если вас интересует, как JVM организует взаимодействие с памятью, какие дает гарантии при обращениях к данным из разных потоков, что такое *переупорядочивание* и *happens-before*, ознакомьтесь с [JSR-133: Java Memory Model and Thread Specification](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf).

Спека довольно сухая и набитая под завязку математикой, поэтому полезно параллельно с чтением смотреть доклад Алексея Шипилева [*"Прагматика Java Memory Model"*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iB2N8aqwtxc) ([слайды](http://shipilev.net/talks/narnia-2555-jmm-pragmatics-en.pdf))

PS. Да и просто почитайте статьи про *Java Memory Model*, их немало.

Comment: спасибо, а то каждый раз как пытаюсь вспомнить , чем volatile отличается от атомарных типов, гуглю. А так пойму основы раз и навсегда.